# Common Lisp reader: customizing intern behavior

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to intercept the behavior of `read` to give some control over the interning of symbols. I might, for example, wish for read to throw an error if a previously uninterned symbol shows up in the input stream. Or perhaps I want to limit the packages in which new symbols can be interned.

Is there a way to hook the interning process without rewriting the reader from scratch?

I am ok with alternate reader implementations. Using `read` itself is not a must.

Comment: Reminds me of: [cl-isolated](https://github.com/kanru/cl-isolated), it provides an alternate reader for code evaluation. Very much restricted ([a feedback](https://www.reddit.com/r/Common_Lisp/comments/f7xmsr/kanruclisolated_a_restricted_environment_for/)). Also [safe-read](https://github.com/phoe/safe-read), which seems less safe, that doesn't intern symbols. Might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the reader defined by the standard without jumping through huge hoops: you'd have to implement the process of accumulating and parsing tokens (including all the number parsing stuff) and then provide suitable ways of intervening.  The standard tells you enough that you should be able to do that, but it's a lot of work: I suspect that most of any reader implementation is that stuff.

Of course specific implementations might provide convenient points at which you can intervene.

The other approach would be to use a portable, extensible reader.  There is at least one thing which may be such a thing: [Eclector](https://github.com/s-expressionists/Eclector), and there may well be others.  I don't know anything about it, unfortunately.